# Pycharm: same code much slower in debugger

Tags: python, pycharm

```
import itertools
x = [p for p in itertools.product(range(0, 10), repeat=5) if (all(p[i] >= p[i + 1] for i in range(4)))]
y=1
```

When I execute this in python console, it takes 1 second. 
When I run this debugger with a breakpoint at "y=1", it takes over 8 hours.

As a novice trying to gain a better understanding of python, can anyone explain why this is the case?

Comment: Do you have any breakpoints set?  Is so disable them.  If this speeds it up, then re-enable to find the slow one.  This snippet ran fine for me under debugger.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Are you sure you didn't just leave it sitting at a breakpoint or something?

Comment: @StephenRauch It actually runs fine for me too in debugger. but if you just add even 1 line after this, (something trivial like x=1) and place a breakpoint on this new line, does it take a very long time now?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. It is executing pretty quickly with debugger enabled.

I think you need to split the list comprehension into multiple lines and put `conditional break points`. Just right click on the break point and put the condition to break.

Comment: @Eddie did you have any breakpoints? It also runs very fast for me in debugger, but as soon as I add another lines and any breakpoints, thats when it becomes very slow. I have edited my original question to reflect this. Thanks.

Comment: I have seen this behavior on several occasions.  My guess is that pycharm is actually hitting the exception represented by the breakpoint and then realizes it is not active then continues.  But this is obviously very slow.  Try putting some dummy lines of code between the breakpoint and the list comprehension.